# BigQuery error: P4 service account needs iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission

Tags: ansible, google-bigquery, schedule

I am scheduling query, my service account has role iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken, but still after run i have an issue
"P4 service account needs iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission". What should i change in IAM of SA?

My SA has role Cloud Scheduler Service Agent(which includes iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken).
Yet, after running

```
bq query 
--display_name='test_query'            
--use_legacy_sql=false 
--target_dataset='test_dataset' 
--schedule='every 24 hours' 
'SELECT * FROM test_table  LIMIT 1'
```

I am facing an error:

```
BigQuery error in query operation: P4 service account needs iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission
```

Also, I run :

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> --member='serviceAccount:<my_service_account>' 
--role='roles/iam.serviceAccountgetAccessToken' and it didn't help.
```

I am expecting the query to be scheduled successfully.

Comment: I wish I had an answer, but I haven't been able to reproduce. Can you describe the environment?

Comment: I am using MAC OS. Entering the GCP first as regular user (jessica.pertich@gmail.com). Chose my project. Enter SA using cmd: gcloud auth activate-service-account --project=my_project --key-file=pass.json
And, then using SA i am trying to schedule query using bq query (described above) and got this error.

Comment: helped with commnd format

Comment: I got the same problem, and it seems solved by running
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <my_project> --member='serviceAccount:<my_service_account>' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountShortTermTokenMinter'
which added a "Credential Minter" role to my service account